# Is there any way to provide animation for soft keyboard appearance in android?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

Keyboard handling is still a major setback in Android app development. Let me be specific about my question, I want to provide **animation for soft keyboard appearance**. I know it is not feasible directly but do anyone know any workaround / tweaks & tricks for this?

Comment: This is too broad. Please explain and add some code block if possible.

Comment: Simple. When my layout's edittext get focus, default soft keyboard gets open. Problem is that, each **OEMs/User** have different keyboard app and they have **different animation speed** for soft keyboard opening. So I want to provide animation speed for soft keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

you can try creating a custom soft keyboard and register your edittext to load this keyboard (take a look at the plethora of custom keyboards you can use https://android-arsenal.com/tag/232)

An example is "Floating KeyboardView" https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5247 shows you how you can customise your keyboard.

Use it as normal keyboard view and

- Place FloatingKeyboardView inside a FrameLayout or a RelativeLayout
  (TIP: Put it last or/and with some elevation)
- Make an xml with your keyboard layout
  (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.html)
- Declare it in activity code

  ```
  FloatingKeyboardView mCustomKeyboard = (FloatingKeyboardView) findViewById(R.id.keyboardview);
  ```
- Assign the keyboard layout

  ```
   mCustomKeyboard.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(this, R.xml.numkbd));
  ```
- Register edittexts to use it

  ```
   mCustomKeyboard.registerEditText(R.id.edittext1);
  ```